# What does "unqualified notion of truth" mean in this passage?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, axiom

From [pages 252-253](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=oGgZWwA2dIgC&pg=PA252&lpg=PA252&dq=laws+truth+%22if+we+consider+bare%22&source=bl&ots=LOKor2GvLA&sig=ACfU3U3UA9R3Fea8Jb6oW5Lgh-AMZImVvQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjpkeL_qbOCAxXCV2wGHXPADcI4ChDoAXoECAIQAw#v=onepage&q=laws%20truth%20%22if%20we%20consider%20bare%22&f=false) of *The Laws of Truth* by Nicholas Smith:

> If we consider bare, uninterpreted closed wffs, we can say that they are true in some models and false in others, but we cannot say that they are simply true or false without qualification. Both translation and valuation yield (different) unqualified notions of truth: translation involves the notion of truth in the actual model; valuation involves the notion of truth in the intended model. Axiomatisation does not yield an unqualified notion of truth. Rather, the notion that emerges naturally in this context is that of a *theorem*: a wff that is true every model that makes all the axioms true. In other words, a theorem is a logical consequence of the axioms. A set of wffs that is closed under logical consequence - that is, one for which every wff that is a logical consequence of some wffs in the set is also in the set - is a *theory*. A set of axioms generates a theory: the set of all wffs that are true in every model in which all the axioms are true.

Could someone please help me understand what might be meant by "unqualified notion of truth" here? In what way is the notion of truth in the actual model (in the case of translation) or intended model (in the case of valuation) "unqualified"?

Aren't they *qualified* notions of truth in the sense that in translation  and valuation, the truth of a closed wff is always determined *relative to* a model and therefore *qualified* by a model?

Comment: Here 'qualified' isn't intuitive and the author simply highlights closed theories under axiomatisation as obviously qualified truths conditioned on axioms ought to be naturally construed as proof-theoretic necessity. If a theory's axioms are inconsistent then this so called 'qualified truth' of theorems are not any type of truth any more. Also the famous logician Hintikka advised not to take such qualified truths for granted if one believes logic ought not to be complete but expressive. OTOH translation/valuation produce real unqualified truth as already clearly explained in your quote...

Comment: Basically, you have to remind the semantics machinery discussed in **Ch.9** with the concluding definition (page 204) of: "true in M". "There are eight types of closed wff [...]. So we have eight *rules telling us how the truth values of closed wffs are determined relative to a given model*." So, the issue is ""unqualified (common sense) notion of truth" vs "formal notion of *truth in a model*".

Comment: Have you understood my answer, which gives you the actual mathematics that you need in order to actually grasp the notion of truth?

Answer (score 6):

### You understood that correctly

A *qualified* truth is simply a truth that is *conditioned*, ie. the truth of it depends on other conditions.

In this case, a theorem is a *qualified truth* in the sense of it being true iff all of the axioms are (accepted as) true.

In other words: theorems are not *absolute* truths, which raises the further question whether such a thing as an *unqualified* truth is even possible to exist. That's something for a different question to consider, though.

Answer (score 3):

The entire point here is that **truth** is **always relative** to an intended model. Any logic textbook worth reading **would precisely define** truth via the satisfaction relation ⊨. It would define when exactly ( M ⊨ Q ) is true, where M is an L-structure and Q is an L-sentence, for some FOL language L. If your book does not define it, then it is impossible for you to gain a fully precise understanding of FOL.

Notice that ⊨ has **two** parameters, one structure and one sentence. Based on this definition it would be simply not sensible to talk about the truth of a sentence in the absence of a structure.

We could (if we wish) define **absolute (unqualified) truth** to be an L-sentence that is true in every L-structure. If we do so, then absolute truths would be exactly the FOL tautologies. And there are countless such unqualified truths, such as:
  ◇ ∀x ( x = x ).
  ◇ ∃w ∀x,y ∃z ( x ≠ z ∧ y ≠ z ) ⇔ ∃x,y,z ( x ≠ y ∧ y ≠ z ∧ z ≠ x ).
  ◇ ∀x ( ∀y ( Q(x,y) ⇒ P(x) ) ) ⇔ ∀x ( ∃y ( Q(x,y) ) ⇒ P(x) ).
  ◇ ∀y ( f(g(y)) = y ) ∧ ∀x ∃y ( g(y) = x ) ⇒ ∀x,y ( f(x) = f(y) ⇒ x = y ).
  (P,Q are predicate-symbols, and f,g are function-symbols.)

Comment: Thank you @user21820. My apologies for the delay in getting back. At the time of posting this question, I was not yet familiar with the idea of semantic entailment, so could not fully understand your answer. I ended up requesting the author to clarify what they meant by "unqualified notion of truth" and they answered as follows: `You are right that the notion of truth on a model is a relative or qualified notion, but the thought is that when we pick out one special model (the actual one, or the intended one), we get an absolute or unqualified notion: truth relative to that model.`

Comment: Does this match with your interpretation of the phrase?

Comment: @user51462: I am not satisfied with the quoted statement because it is misleading. Even for arithmetical sentences, there is no way to be sure you have picked out ℕ, without it being relative to your foundational system. Secondly, I do not think it is reasonable to call such a notion "absolute" or "unqualified". One can invent new meanings for existing words, but given that the author failed to define "absolute" prior to the confusing statements, it is fair to call his usage misleading as it runs contrary to the standard English meaning.

Comment: Yes, the author is usually very thorough in their explanatons, so I wasn't sure if I had misunderstood something.

Comment: @user51462: Did that author give mathematically precise definitions at all? If not, I suggest that you switch to texts written by professional logicians. I can assure you that, even if an explanation sounds thorough, it means very little unless there is a precise mathematical notion behind it. You can check my SE profile page for my recommended logic texts. If you would like to discuss further with me in chat, just let me know your mathematical background and we will go from there!

Comment: That would be great, thank you (coincidentally, I came across [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1684208/51462) some days ago). The book does not give many mathematically precise definitions, but I think this is due to it being an introductory text for undergraduate students from a wide variety of disciplines. The author is usually very careful and complete in their explanations, much more so than the authors of the other introductory texts I have attempted. So I'm grateful to have found it and will finish it, but I am starting to feel the need for something more rigorous.

Comment: @user51462: That's right; that post is the one I was referring to. I'm guessing that you do not yet have undergraduate mathematics background. So ping me in [this chat-room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77161/basic-mathematics)!

Comment: Thank you, I have messaged you there.

Answer (score 1):

"Unqualified notion of truth" I think would correspond to Goedel's notion that arithmetic statements are true but we can't always prove them in our system of axioms, by the incompleteness theorem.  Nicholas Smith pursues a less Platonist philosophy of mathematics, where the existence of an "intended (or standard) model" is not assumed.  As  you point out, he does mention the "intended model" but this is not an absolute term but rather a relative one.

Namely, what he calls "the actual model" may be an extension of what has been sociologically accepted by mathematicians as the "intended model".  For a discussion of intended models and sociology see this [recent question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/457042/28128) at MO.

Comment: I didn't downvote. The author intends that the 'intended model' is an absolute term not a relative one. The intended model of the theory PA is obviously N without any relativity, and the 'actual model' could be the objective world as its own model as reified intersubjectivity in philosophy jargon which could be consistent with your proposed extension of what has been sociologically accepted by mathematicians as the "intended model". Any intended model be it N or V=L is meant in the metalanguage per Tarski, otherwise PA/ZFC can prove their won consistency trivially...

Comment: Since the purview of ZFC is huge and possibly inaccessible and ineffable in the sense of Cantor semiotics, our normal intentionality can't intuit at least intersubjectively (socially) contrast to the much tamed though infinite model N expressed by our mundane metalanguage of commonly intuited unqualified (unconditioned) metaphysics, which produce the OP quoted 'unqualified' truth via valuation...

Comment: @DoubleKnot, thanks for your comments.  I will have to think about what you write on ZFC.  The point is not so much models of ZFC as models of P(N) namely R, where there is already a dispute with regard to the "minimal model".  For example, if V=L then P(N) will satisfy CH, but other models will not.  You also wrote: "N [is] expressed by our mundane metalanguage".  I think this is subject to dispute, as I mention in my MO post.

Comment: @DoubleKnot, with regard to your comment that "The intended model of the theory PA is obviously N without any relativity" : I am not sure what your background is exactly, but let me make the following comment.  Suppose N is uniquely determined as you assert.  Now consider P(N) of this N.  Does P(N) contain sets of intermediate cardinality between N and R?  If N is uniquely determined, there (apparently) should be a unique answer to that question.  How do you explain that?

Comment: Most people including Cantor and Gödel intended ZF standard model V=L should be 1st order constructible as commonly intuited, and if so there's really not much difference between ZFC and PA (both have nonstandard models of arbitrary cardinalities) except perhaps axiom of infinity, and thus CH holds as intended. But Cohen's forcing result indicates ZFC could be more dynamically intricate and the various inaccessible cardinals could exist either in the intended cumulative hierarchy V or forced multiverses V[G]s or some other ineffable way. So for nonconstructivists the 'intended' model is not...

Comment: @DoubleKnot, you wrote: "Most people including Cantor and Gödel intended ZF standard model V=L should be 1st order constructible as commonly intuited, and if so there's really not much difference between ZFC and PA."  That's a valuable input.  I take it then you disagree with Kossak as literally interpreted?  You may want to leave an answer there: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457042/standard-models-of-n-and-r-an-alice-bob-approach